# How to remove script's parent directory using os Module?

Tags: python, operating-system

I am currently making a python program which runs some specific lines of code, then remove itself. I am using this code:

```
import os
os.remove("program.py")
```

Where **`program.py`** is the name of my program which will delete itself. But, my program is in a directory "Self-Delete" and I want to remove that directory, too. How can I do that?
In short, I want to remove the directory in which my program is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `os.rmdir(dir_path)` for deleteing folder
and can find parent folder by `../` path
and

To get the full path to the directory a Python file is contained in, write this in that file:

```
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

for example if you want remove parent folder can use sample code:

```
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
os.remove("program.py")
os.rmdir(dir_path)
```

or if you want remove parent of parent can use

```
import os
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
parent_dir = os.path.join(dir_path, "../")
os.remove("program.py")
os.rmdir(parent_dir)
```